# Convergent limit $\lim_{n\to+\infty} \left(\frac{(3^n-1)^2-9^n}{\sqrt{9^n+n^9}}\right)$ which seems divergent by graph.

Tags: limits, analysis, graphing-functions

Question $$\lim_{n\to+\infty} \left(\frac{(3^n-1)^2-9^n}{\sqrt{9^n+n^9}}\right)$$
My solution $$=\lim_{n\to+\infty} \left(\frac{9^n-2\cdot3^n+1-9^n}{\sqrt{9^n\cdot(1+\frac{n^9}{9^n})}}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{n\to+\infty} \left(\frac{-2+\frac{1}{3^n}}{\sqrt{(1+\frac{n^9}{9^n})}}\right)$$
$$= \frac{0-2}{\sqrt{1+0}}$$
$$=-2$$

But the graph of this sequence looks divergent.
[image: Graph]

Comment: $-2$ looks right to me. The graphing software must be wrong.

Comment: I think your work is fine. The plotting may be suffering from numerical instability of some sort.

Comment: In fact the graph goes to -2 very nicely until about $n=20$. After that you are seeing numerical artifacts due to the subtraction of huge numbers.

Comment: Try plotting $$f(x)=\frac{-2 + \frac{1}{3^x}}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{x^9}{9^x}}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is fine, as an alternative way to check the result we can proceed as follows

- $(3^n-1)^2-9^n=((3^n-1)+3^n)((3^n-1)-3^n)\sim -2\cdot 3^n$
- $\sqrt{9^n+n^9}\sim \sqrt{9^n}=3^n$

that is

$$\frac{(3^n-1)^2-9^n}{\sqrt{9^n+n^9}} \sim \frac{ -2\cdot 3^n}{3^n} \to -2$$

As noticed, the problem with the graph is a numerical issue since exponential terms grow very fast ([here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%28%283%5Ex-1%29%5E2-9%5Ex%29%2F%289%5Ex%2Bx%5E9%29%5E.5%20for%20x%3D1..1000%20and%20y%3D-3..0) a better graph obtained by WA). As a suggestion, we should be very careful when evaluating or check limits by graphs, better to try with alternative ways to obtain the result.

Comment: I don't like your suggestion. Graphs can be very useful tools. Better to say "we should be careful when evaluating..."

Comment: @TonyK Maybe I wasn't clear with that point. I mean that if we become confident with more methods, for elementary limits we never need to look the graph to guess the solution. For that reason I suggest to make a lot of exercises to become confident with that. I'm not excluding theuse of graph in general but as for the present case they can induce in strongly wrong eveluation. In any case I think your suggestion is fine to better express the concept. Thanks to have pointed it out. Regards

Comment: @TonyK Moreover to make a good graph we need a calculator and I suppose its use is not allowed during homework or exams. With the software at disposal one can better check the result directly inquiring for the limt itself. This is of course my experience with the matter, I've never used graph to evaluate the limit with the exclusion of vertical asympthotes when studying the graph of functions. But I don't want be categoricalwith that, I can't exclude that in some case it could be useful. Anyway I suggest to avoid that as a current method to solve or check. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just starting to learn the limits and graphs are the only way I came up with to check the answers(and the exercise is not HW and has no standard solution..). So also thanks for the alternative way of checking.

Comment: @SixTwelfthsPi Well done! To check the result you can also use WA as [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+%28%283%5En-1%29%5E2-9%5En%29%2F%289%5En%2Bn%5E9%29%5E.5+as+n+-%3Einf). There is nothing bad to do so but always after some trial by hands. Bye